# A string vector inside an int vector?

Tags: c++, vector

I'm aware of multidimensional vectors for example `vector<vector<int>>` but I was wondering if you can have a vector of a type inside a vector of another type.

An example would be a string vector inside an integer vector, so I would access it like this:

```
vectorName[0]["A"];
```

Can this be done?

Thanks.

Comment: You can't even do `vectorName["A"]` in the first place. Why don't you start with that?

Answer (score 3):

This expression is more appropriate for declaration

```
std::vector<std::map<std::string, T>> vectorName;
```

In this case you will be able to write for example

```
T value = vectorName[0]["A"];
```

where T is some type.

Answer (score 1):

`std::vector` is a random access data structure by design, and is supposed to store a contiguous data array where the elements are accessible via an **integral index number**.

You can *not* use `std::vector` in the way you describe, it seems more like a string->value_type mapping, e.g. `std::map<std::string, T>`.

You could use a `std::vector` of `std::map`s to get the behaviour you want.

```
std::vector<std::map<std::string, int>> vec{
    {{"a1", 1}, {"a2", 2}},
    {{"b1", 1}, {"b2", 2}}
};

std::cout << vec[0]["a2"] << std::endl; // 2
```